# How to include authorization header in GET request to secured endpoint in Spring with JWT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Im using Spring-Security and JWT library to generate token. When the user is authenticated i get the authorization token in response:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ...
```

In all tutorials I've seen authors pasting this token in authorization header when sending a GET request using POSTMAN, but no tutorial how it works in real request. Although in my Postman it works when I paste in the headers and I'm getting 200 OK.

I'm wondering how can I include this header in real code?

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;
    private final SecretKey secretKey;


    public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, 
            JwtConfig jwtConfig,
            SecretKey secretKey) {

        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException { 

        try {       
        System.out.println("Authentication token " + request.getInputStream());
        UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = 
                new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), 
                UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);


        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUsername(), 
                authenticationRequest.getPassword()
        );



        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
        return authenticate;

        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("new runtime exception " + e);
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authResult.getName())
            .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(jwtConfig.getTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
            .signWith(secretKey)
            .compact();

       System.out.println("This is token: " + token);   
       response.addHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader(), jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + token);

    } 





}
```

**EDIT**

Here's my frontend request. After this call I get Response headers with authorization token. Now the question is how can I use this token to implement future requests? :

```
$.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: "/login",
                      data: JSON.stringify({
                          "username" : "linda",
                          "password" : "password",

                      }),
                      success: function(response) {
                         // some logic
                         },

                      error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                      },
                      processData: false,
                      //dataType: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    });
```

Comment: where are you using your program? or specifically what is your front-end framework?

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm using simple jQuery ajax call, but I don't mind to use other if you had a solution in other javascript framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated, you want to store the returned token on the client side using either local storage or session storage. Next, you will protect any route/endpoint which requires said token (protected route) . There should be an authorization guard in place which checks to see if token is present in the header (in the same format as you've used it when sending requests via Postman). If the token is invalid or missing from the header altogether, it will usually redirect to a different route (often the login page).

This isn't specific to Spring, but to JSON Web Tokens. The implementation differs from one language/framework to the next, bus as far as I know, this is always the general procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Single page frameworks like angular or react because the provide better tools. But what framework you are using completely depends on your application. for JQuery and javascript you can use this:

you must store the token inside your browser. one of the ways is using "local storage":

```
  success: function(response) {
    // not sure how you send token
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.token)
  },
```

and add token header to ajax request after that. note that you must handle empty token or expired token in your code.

```
token = localStorage.getItem('token')
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
})
//call ajax
```

Comment: That would be working for post request. But more important how can I access secured endpoint e.g "/api/clients" which requires an authorization header with token obtained when getting authenticated? So far I'm getting 403

Comment: using ajaxSetup and storing token into local storage **after** obtaining the token must do the job. check the notwork tab of your browser to check if it sends the header in a proper format or not.

Comment: I sends headers only for post, im not making ajax call requests. If I wanted that I would need to ajax get. Threre must be a way to capture this header on the server side and inject it when making get